# SendGrid SendGrid\Mail\Mail() not found while sending email in Heroku

Tags: php, email, heroku, sendgrid

I want to send emails from my php application which is deployed in heroku using sendgrid api for that i wrote some code and i executed my code locally and i am able to send the email using sendgrid API later i tried to deploy the same code in heroku but there i am getting error like  `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SendGrid\Mail\Mail' not found in /app/send_email.php:7`. I tried to change the path of `SendGrid\Mail()` but it's not working at all.
Here i installed the sendgrid API using composer and i had added sendgrid addon in my heroku as well.

Can anyone help me on how to make sendgrid api work in heroku

This is my send_mail.php code

```
    <?php
         require 'vendor/autoload.php';
         class SendEmail{
         public static function SendMail($to,$subject,$content, $attachment_content){
             $key = '***********************************';
             $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();  // <-------- Error here
             $email->setFrom("123@123.com",$sender);
             $email->setSubject($subject);
             $email->addTo($to);
             $email->addContent("text/html",$content);
             $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($key);
             
            // Attachment
             $content = file_get_contents($attachment_content[0]);
             $attachment = new \SendGrid\Mail\Attachment();
             $attachment->setType("multipart/mixed");
             $attachment->setFilename($attachment_content[1].".png");
             $attachment->setContentId($attachment_content[1]);
             $attachment->setDisposition("attachment");
             $attachment->setContent($content);
            
            $email->addAttachment($attachment);
             try{
                 $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
                echo "Mail sent successfully"; 
             }catch(Exception $e){
                 echo 'Email exception Caught : '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
                 return false;
              }
         }
     }

?>
```

Comment: Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here. I'm not that familiar with PHP on Heroku, so could you give some more details. For example, how did you install the SendGrid PHP library into your application locally? And are you sure that the Heroku deploy is also installing it?

Comment: @philnash. I installed sendgrid in my project via composer like executing command composer require sendgrid/sendgrid. After installing it i checked my composer.json there i am able to see the sendgrid with version number.

Comment: And does the composer install also work when you deploy to Heroku?

Comment: @philnash, yes it's working. I mean it's saying like installing dependencies. I can able to see the composer.json file with sendgrid package version number

Comment: In your code you `require 'vendor/autoload.php'`. In the [Heroku guide to getting started with PHP](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php?singlepage=true#declare-app-dependencies) the example app does `require('../vendor/autoload.php')`. Is that something?

Comment: @philnash. No luck. I tried what you had mentioned above but still same error was occurred. I tried to set the path of send grid mail api manually like /vendor/sendgrid/sendgrid/lib/mail/Mail(). But no use. Any other way for the solution ??

Comment: I want you to be successful with this, but as I'm not a PHP developer I'm running out of ideas. I would suggest trying to build on [Heroku's example PHP app](https://github.com/heroku/php-getting-started) that they reference in their [getting started with PHP guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php). When you get that running successfully on Heroku you could try adding SendGrid and your code to that application and seeing whether that works better?